# 3d card flip effect with css not showing back

Tags: css

I have a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nLhgT/
I followed the instructions here http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip and http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html When I flip the card, only the front side is being shown (flipped). I can't seem to get the backface to show. I've read similar questions on stackoverflow saying the backface must be rotated first. It is indeed rotated initially in my example.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front">
                front
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                back
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
}
.card div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front {
  background: red;
}
.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card.flip {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

JS

```
  $(document.body).on('click', '.card', function() {
          console.log("CLICK");
    document.querySelector('.card').classList.toggle("flip");
  });
```

The only difference in my example is that the card is within an unordered list. I intend to make a list of these cards. But I don't think that should affect things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the main problem is that `preserve-3d` isn't supported by IE. Huge bummer, but not much that can be done about it. Therefore, you should be applying the transform to each child element, not the entire card.

The best way I've found of making a card flip is as follows:

- Transform each face. The front should default to 0, the back to 180. When flipped, they should be 180 and 360 respectively.
- Apply a `z-index` to them. The visible face should have something like 10, while the hidden one has 0. This ensures that the right one is in front at all times (even in browsers that don't support transformations)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nLhgT/25/) is my update to your Fiddle showing a working card flip.

Comment: Why mixing of vanilla `js` with `jQuery`, isn't it better `$('.card').toggleClass("flip");` [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/nLhgT/26/) ?

Comment: Because I couldn't be arsed to change the jQuery. Personally, I'd just [ditch it completely](http://vanilla-js.com/), but since it wasn't a barrier to answering the question I just let it be.

Comment: And anyway, it would be `$(this).toggleClass("flip")`, unless you want every single card to flip over when you just click one of them.

Comment: This is so far the best answer I found. It is nice and simple in the demo. As Niet points out I believe you do need to flip the front and back respectively in IE 10 which is what I did!

Answer (score 3):

Here you go...

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLhgT/17/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="container" id="flip-toggle">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front">front</div>
                <div class="back">back</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    width: 300px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 800px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#flip-toggle.flip .card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter:"FlipH";
}
.container, .front, .back {
     width: 300px;
    height: 260px;
}
.card {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.front {
    background: red;
    z-index: 2;
}
.back {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.card', function () {
      console.log("CLICK");
      document.querySelector('#flip-toggle').classList.toggle('flip');
  });
```

Comment: I still don't see the back.

Comment: Strange..I am able to see back in both chrome and firefox in my fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/nLhgT/17/  ...anyway your solution is working...so harry may take it.

Comment: Maybe it's because "make it work in IE and it works in all other browsers" has always been my driving plan of action ;) As mentioned, IE doesn't support `preserve-3d`, therefore it it flattening the front side and transforming that.